# WPF - clicking on a button inside an user control doesn't call the command, and neither does clicking on the control itself

Tags: wpf, mvvm, user-controls, command

I have a serious issue with binding any command to my user control. Everything compiles, but the command is never called. I have tried two approaches - first, I tried to bind the command to a button inside my control, and when I was unable to do it, I tried to bind the command to an inputcommand of the control itself to see if it would work. It didn't. The control itself is within an ItemsControl, in case that matters.
Here's a simplified version of what I did. In the xaml.cs file of the control:

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CloseCommandProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
      "CloseCommand",
      typeof(ICommand),
      typeof(Thumbnail),
      new UIPropertyMetadata(null)
    );

    public ICommand CloseCommand
    {
        get { return (ICommand)GetValue(CloseCommandProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CloseCommandProperty, value); }
    }
```

In the UserControl's xaml file, the offending button (the UserControl has Name="Control", and Hash is another dependency property):

```
<Button Command="{Binding ElementName=Control, Path=CloseCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=Control, Path=Hash}">
                <TextBlock Text="X"/></Button>
```

Now, a simplified (irrelevant properties not included) datatemplate part of the xaml file of the view (which has a datacontext, if that matters), where I use this control:

```
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <local:Thumbnail Hash="{Binding Hash}"
                                         CloseCommand="{Binding ElementName=Control, Path=DataContext.RemoveImageCommand}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

Just for the sake of completeness, I'll include the command from the viewmodel.

```
private bool CanRemoveImageCommandExecute(string hash)
{
    return true;
}
private void RemoveImageCommandExecute(string hash)
{
    MessageBox.Show("ABC","ABC");
}
public ICommand RemoveImageCommand
{
    get { return new RelayCommand<string>(RemoveImageCommandExecute, CanRemoveImageCommandExecute);}
}
```

The RelayCommand class comes from MicroMVVM, and it just creates a command from two functions (and works everywhere else).

Can you tell me why clicking the button does nothing and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that, even though I wasted a few hours on that, I was too quick to ask the question. Literally a few minutes after posting it, I realized that my binding in ItemTemplate is wrong.
The problem was that I used ElementName instead of RelativeSource:

```
CloseCommand="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=local:AddImage}
```

Where local:AddImage is the name of the view which has the DataContext set to the viewmodel..